# Vim visual to x^th character

Tags: vim

So I know to do a visual from the current cursor position to a character is `vt[char]` but what if I want to do a visual from current position to the second instance of that character?

For example I have this line:

`<TextBox x:Name="tbPreEventTime" Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties:Settings.Default}, Path=CameraBeforeTS }"`

And I want to copy from the `{` to the `}` that appears at the very end or the second instance of the bracket

Comment: Use `v2t{`, or `vt{` then `;`. See `:help t` (also `:help ;`, which is right below).

Answer (score 3):

You can do `vi{` or `va{` depending on if you want the curly braces to be included (not included with (`v`) select (`i`) in (`{`) braces). If the cursor is in nested braces, you can do `v2i{` to do the one 1 level up.

Also, if your cursor is on or after the first or second curly brace you can use a combination of `vf}`, `v2f}`, `vF{`, `v2F{`, `vt}`, `v2t}`, `vT{`, or `v2T{`.

Finally, remember that while in visual mode, you can hit `o` to move the "other side". When paired with the above, you could avoid using the `vi{` style command, but I don't know why you would want to.